# Integrate excel with asp.net web application using open XML

Tags: asp.net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to use excel application on the web like google docs from asp.net web application using open XML.How can I do it?

Comment: "*How can I do it?*" we need your effort...[Whate have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload open xml SpreadsheetML and allow user to edit in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259194/upload-open-xml-spreadsheetml-and-allow-user-to-edit-in-asp-net)